# Neighbourhood of a disc

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm a bit confused on how to write down *precisely* a neighborhood on an example. My question is the following:

Suppose I have a disc $\Omega=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{C}, |x-1|<2.5\rbrace$ and its closure

$\bar{\Omega}=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{C}, |x-1|\leq2.5\rbrace$

How can I explicitly write a neighborhood (or any example of a neighborhood, I understand that there is no unique one) of $\bar{\Omega}$?

Suppose I want to consider some function $F$ that sends neighborhood of $\bar{\Omega}$ to $\Omega$. Which set can I take as this neighborhood? Could any set

$\lbrace x\in\mathbb{C}, |x-1|<r\rbrace$

with $r>2.5$ be an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question, but the set you list at the bottom is indeed a neighborhood of $\overline \Omega$ for all $r>2.5$.

Comment: Yes, pick any open ball that contains $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider any open neighbourhood, so long as it contains $\overline{\Omega}$, so I would use:

for some $\rho\gt 0$, $\{x\in\Bbb C:|x-1|\lt 2.5+\rho\}$